# Does 1 channel mean the sound is mono?

Tags: windows, audio

I used [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) to get info about some audios. It shows 1 channel for some and 2 channels for others. Does it mean that sounds with 1 channel are mono and those with two channels are stereo ?

Comment: Note that "mono" and "stereo" are short for monophonic and stereophonic.

Comment: Or monaural @saw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, channel in audio is a stream of information.

> An audio device supports one or more channels depending on configuration. Mono audio has one channel, stereo two channels, and 5.1 surround has six channels.

[Source](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20audio%20channel&oq=define%20audio%20channel&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&q=audio%20channel&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=toGJULHzKYmw8AThkYGgDw&ved=0CB4QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=80ef5323c76d6b79&bpcl=35466521&biw=1083&bih=781)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Generally 1 channel audio can still be played through a stereo headset or speakers, it is just the same signal going to both instead of a signal going to each side.